# How to override Spring boot Consul config properties?

Tags: spring, consul, spring-profiles

I use a distributed Consul config in my application, and it works well. But also i want to override some config properties, when i start an application with different Spring profile. Fo example, i define Kafka server address in the main Consul configuration:

```
    spring:
      kafka:
        bootstrap-servers: some_kafka:9092
```

and i want to use different address when i switch to Spring profile named "local":

```
    spring:
      kafka:
        bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
```

How to do it? I tried using bootstrap file with suffix (bootstrap-local.yml) and Consul profile-depended setings (stored in folder "application,local/"), but it does't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to override the properties from consul, you first need to add two properties in your consul file to enable the override. The properties are:

```
"spring.cloud.config.allowOverride": "true",
"spring.cloud.config.overrideSystemProperties": "false"
```

Please check [this](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#overriding-bootstrap-properties) for more details.

Once that is done, you can now override the properties by using a JVM parameter, from your example, will be: `-Dspring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092` or you can do the same with a `bootstrap-local.yml` and setting the active profile to `local`